# Appending a string to a line in file matching a pattern

Tags: linux, string

I have a file whose contents looks like

*File.txt*

```
561 8c:7b:9d:37:0c:ce
546 00:19:55:17:df:f4
345 f0:c1:f1:69:5e:e6
```

In a shell script,

```
var_mac = 00:19:55:17:df:f4 [some mac]
```

and another variable for `var_mac`

```
val_mac = "store"
```

I want to find the `var_mac` in *File.txt* and append the `val_mac` at the end of the line which matches `var_mac`.

i.e

```
561 8c:7b:9d:37:0c:ce
546 00:19:55:17:df:f4   store
345 f0:c1:f1:69:5e:e6
```

Answer (score 1):

Put these in a file, call it a shell script.

```
var_mac="00:19:55:17:df:f4"
val_mac="store"
sed "/$var_mac/ s/$/ $val_mac/" File.txt
561 8c:7b:9d:37:0c:ce
546 00:19:55:17:df:f4 store
345 f0:c1:f1:69:5e:e6
```

If you find it does what you want add a flag -i to sed to do the change in-file.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl \
  -i.bak \
  -ne 'chomp;
       $_ .= "  $ENV{val_mac}" if m/^\d+ (\S+)/ && $1 eq $ENV{var_mac};
       print "$_\n";' \
  File.txt
```

`-i.bak` causes perl to operate on the input file in-place but to leave a backup copy in `File.txt.bak`.

`-ne` means "treat the following as a program to run on each line in the input"

The first line and last line of the perl script shuffle newlines.

`$_ .= "  $ENV{val_mac}"` appends the value from the environment variable to the end of the line.

`if m/^\d+ (\S+)/ && $1 eq $ENV{var_mac}` checks whether the second column exists and matches the mac address from the `var_mac` environment variable.